# Code Path Issue while calling Subroutine

Tags: vb.net

What is wrong with this example? I can't get it to continue the original code path. It executes *Options.LoadAccount()* successfully and then just stops. I've tried creating a new instance of *Options* but it just produced an error and suggested I switch it back to the example below.

This is the startup form.

```
Public Class Loading

    Private Sub Loading_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Load Account
        Loading("Loading Account")
        Options.LoadAccount()

        'Load Points
        Loading("Loading Point Settings")
        Options.LoadPoints()

        Main.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Loading(msg As String)
        lblStatus.Text = msg
        lblStatus.Refresh()
        loadBar.PerformStep()
        loadBar.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This class or form hasn't been loaded yet, but breakpoints prove the *Sub LoadAccount()* is executed, but breakpoints also proves the code path does not return to *Public Class Loading* and execute *Options.LoadPoints()*. Why?

```
Public Class Options
    Public Shared Sub LoadAccount()
        Options.User = GetSetting("UTB", "Account", "User")
        Options.OAuth = GetSetting("UTB", "Account", "OAuth")
        Options.Channel = GetSetting("UTB", "Account", "Channel")
        Options.AuthCode = GetSetting("UTB", "Account", "AuthCode")
        Options.ChannelTitle = GetSetting("UTB", "Account", "ChannelTitle")
        Options.Game = GetSetting("UTB", "Account", "Game")
        Options.Delay = GetSetting("UTB", "Account", "Delay")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you probably have an exception which will not show in form load (they can get eaten there).  Move the code to Form Shown and It will be revealed.  That LoadAccount looks funky - what does `Options.User` refer to?  When debugging you can step into procedures like LoadAccount - if you did, you might see it stop debugging at one line or another - thats where the exception is

Comment: Helpful as always, @Plutonix This is answer.. Form_Load did eat my exception. I am able to fix the issue from here. Thank you for pointing out Form_Shown as an option. Propose this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Its not really an answer but how to diagnose.  The real problem was probably a NullReference?

Comment: It was because I was trying to set an empty string to an integer.

Comment: This happens sometimes in vb.net when the error occurs inside some initialization, either in a Dim or occasionally in a Load handler.